# what is different between two codes?

Tags: r

I don't know what is different between two codes. When I use **ml.norm(iris[1:4], mode="uv",na.rm=FALSE)** and **dh.norm(iris[1:4], mode="uv",na.rm=FALSE)**, the results are different..`

```
ml.norm <- function(x, mode="uv", na.rm=FALSE){
if(class(x)=="data.frame"){
    x <- as.matrix(x)
} 
else{
    return (apply(x,2,ml.norm, mode=mode, na.rm=na.rm))
}
if (mode =="uv"){
    x = x/sd(x, na.rm=na.rm)
}
else if (mode =="z"){
    x = (x-mean(x))/sd(x, na.rm=na.rm)
}
else{stop(paste("unknow mode", mode))}
return(x)
}


dh.norm <- function (x,mode="uv",na.rm=FALSE) {
# need to check if x is a matrix
if (is.data.frame(x)) {
    x=as.matrix(x)
}
if (is.matrix(x)) {
    return(apply(x,2,dh.norm,mode=mode,na.rm=na.rm))
}
if (mode == "uv") {
    x = x/sd(x,na.rm=na.rm)
} else if (mode == "z") {
    # your code here
    x = (x - mean(x))/sd(x,na.rm=na.rm)
} else {
    stop(paste("unknown mode",mode))
}
return(x)    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ml.norm`

IF x IS data.frame DO convert it into a matrix. THEN check mode and DO stuff.

`dh.norm`

IF x IS a data.frame DO convert it into a matrix. THEN check if x is a matrix and apply dh.norm on the columns. THEN check the mode and DO stuff.

So `ml.norm` is missing the `return(apply(x,2,[YOUR FUNCTION],mode=mode,na.rm=na.rm))`  part if you run it on a data.frame.